# small overlay on circular photo

Tags: html, css

Hi im working on a personal website and I want to have a circular photo with the bottom ~10% filled in on which I can put some text. [Here is  picture to better describe what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwK7o.jpg) If anyone can point me to a tutorial or show me how to do this that would be great.

Comment: Could you provide any html/css that you have written already? We can help with any issues you run into.

Comment: @chazsolo I am using the code shown in the accepted answer below. I now want to make it responsive but I can't seem to get it right. There is always something that scales out of proportion.

Comment: From your other comment, are you saying that you want the containing circle to expand relative to the size of the window?

Comment: Yes indeed. I want the entire circle and content to expand relative to the window size. I was trying some stuff using 'auto' and percentages but i can't seem to get it right.

Comment: You're going to want to set the height and width of the circle based on the width of the page or containing element. If your browser support can handle it, look into `vw` units, or use percentages with media queries.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.img-container {
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.img-container > .caption {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 123;
}
.img-container > img {
  max-height: 100%;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container" >

<img src="http://assets.barcroftmedia.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/assets/images/recent-images-11.jpg">

<div class="caption" >CAPTION</div>

</div>
```

I think you are looking for this..

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot. I should be able to look at that now and customize it the way I need.

Comment: I did accept it. I have another question for you. Do you know how to make this responsive. I have been fooling around with it for a bit but I can't seem to make it responsive. I want it to scale with the page so that it takes up the same amount of space no matter which screen you are using.